# BIOS loads slower after removing linux dual boot (grub)

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I removed a ubuntu dual boot partition from my computer recently, using this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Before, it would boot right into grub instantly, and I could choose Windows or Linux from there. But after removing it, BIOS spends several seconds with a little "loading" wheel before booting into Windows.

- MSI z170A gaming m5 motherboard, MSI Click BIOS 5 software
- Windows 10 installed on an m.2 nvme drive (though it did the same thing before I cloned it to there)

What the disk looks like

[image]

Any other info that seems pertinent, let me know and I'll provide it

Comment: What procedure did you use to remove GRUB?

Comment: @grawity the method in the URL at the top: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Which part of it? Just removing the `EFI\ubuntu` directory?

Comment: @grawity  yes I believe so. After following those steps it booted without GRUB correctly